# How to convert a xml element into url using css?

Tags: css, xml

I have an xml file which has an element like this

```
<video><title>XXXX</title><url>VIDEO ID OF YOUTUBE></url></video>
```

Is there any way to use CSS to display the  elements as

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/videoid">XXXX</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of a way to use CSS for this. But you can do this using a XSLT Stylesheet. Is that what you want? Then a XSLT Stylesheet similar to this can help you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" >
    <body>

      <xsl:apply-templates select ="/items/video"/>

    </body>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="video" >
    <li>
      <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
          <xsl:value-of select="./url" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="./title"/>
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match=
    "*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) 
     and normalize-space()=''
      ]"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes that the XML input file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<items>
  <video>
    <title>XXXX</title>
    <url>VIDEO ID OF YOUTUBE></url>
  </video>
  <video>
    <title>XXXX</title>
    <url>VIDEO ID OF YOUTUBE></url>
  </video>
</items>
```

Exactly how you should do the transform is hard to say when I don't know about your requirements. A XSLT transform can be done in a number of ways. If the XML input file is static one can let the webbrowser do the transformation. If the XML file is on a server you can write a transform in a awebpage and sen the HTML to the webbbrowser. It all depens on your environment.

Comment: Can you help me understand how to make VIDEO ID into full Youtube url please. The video Id is the last part of the youtube url which is stored in the xml. http://www.youtube.com/v=[Video-ID]

Comment: @FloodGravemind sorry for replying so late. But if you want to parse out the actual ID of the video you need to use a Regular Expression. Again, it all depends on what your sourcefiles looks like.

Answer (score 2):

CSS is for Styling, if you wish to read XML and produce HTML Content you should use Javascript. Or any server side language if you want it to be done before sending it to the client browser.

Answer (score 1):

As Nicklas points out, many think of Css to be intended to be for styling and nothing more. More generally, though, it's intended for the presentation of your information. This is a fringe case that's difficult for me to say whether it's going too far or within the scope of CSS: is this simply changing the presentation, or is it doing something more?

I'm sure many, like Nicklas, would argue that what you want to do goes beyond the intended purpose of CSS. And I'd probably agree with Nicklas in that for most cases I'd find this to be a less-than-ideal way to go about things.

With that said, [it is possible](http://jsfiddle.net/Sh7jJ/)

```css
#url:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "<a href=\"http://www.youtube.com/";
}  
#url:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\">";
}
#text:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "</a>";
}
```

*Note: I used Html in this example for the sake of making a JsFiddle, but the same strategy should work for an Xml file*